# Make some clean up after user automatically logged out in Asp.Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, katana

I am using `ASP.NET Identity 2.0` in ASP.NET MVC 5 application and for some reason I am storing some data in database which has to be cleaned after the user is logged out. I set `ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sessionTimeOut)` property in `CookieAuthenticationProvider` but I need to execute a method after the `TimeSpan` has expired. I tried to add `Session_End` method in `Global.asax` but did not work.

Is there any way to execute a callback function when the user is automatically logged out from the system ?

Comment: A user is automatically logged out when their authentication cookie(s) expire.  No server events are executed as the cookie is maintained by the client.  In order to attempt to detect an automatic logout, you would need to track actual user logins along with the expected cookie expiration in some sort of data store.  If you have a sliding expiration, you would need to update that value when the cookie's expiration time changes.  Then, you would need to have some function that looks at that data to find users whose expiration time is past due in order to do your cleanup.

Comment: Like @Tommy said, it is handled client side for the most part. As web developers, we are at the mercy of the users logging-in and the logging out minus the whole "sliding expiration." In the past I have used jQuery Idle Session handlers to handle the timeout portion of things, once it hits the timeout event, it will call an Action on a Controller.  One that I have used in the past is: https://github.com/kidh0/jquery.idle

Comment: I am thinking of using SignalR to make the clean up in OnDisconnected method but I am afraid this method will execute multiple times even if the user is logged in and it will cause a lot problems if this method is executed multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tommy and @Kevin B Burns recommended I could not find a specific solution provided from `ASP.MVC` itself  but ended up using [`Quartz.NET`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/) job scheduler to execute for a specific time to make the clean up in database.